# Is the terminal in netbeans just cygwin?

Tags: netbeans

I have been working away with cygwin to type `g++ and ./a.out` commands when I noticed netbeans has a terminal window that works the same way. What is that terminal window made from? Is it the same thing as cygwin? What's the difference between cygwin, netbeans terminal, and windows terminal `(run->cmd)` and why don't `g++ and ./a.out` work in the windows terminal?

Answer (score 3):

When I try to start a new local terminal in netbeans under windows I get a message saying cygwin is required.

So I'm going to go with yes :)